# How to use a variable in multiple tests (gtest)?

Tags: c++, googletest

I want to have an object that takes longer to initialize to use across multiple tests. It doesn't want to initialize, I get an error:

> cygwin_exception::open_stackdumpfile: Dumping stack trace to HodnotenieFilmov.exe.stackdump

It worked when I included different files across the project, but then other things got broken. E.g. I included FilmDatabase.cpp instead of FilmDatabase.h, but now including .cpp gives me multiple definition error.

Here's a snippet of the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "gtest/gtest.h"
#include "FilmDatabase.h"

FilmDatabase database("Database.csv");     // <-- the problem
using namespace ::testing;

TEST(Database, GenreDrama) {
    vector<Movie> films = database.getMoviesByGenre("DRamA");
    ASSERT_EQ(films.size(), 4360);
}

TEST(Database, TagAnime) {
    FilmDatabase db(database);
    vector<Movie> anime = db.getMoviesByTag("aniME");
    ASSERT_EQ(anime.size(), 12);
}
```

Comment: Not 100% sure, but you may be looking for `extern`.

Comment: What it means: `an object that takes longer to initialize`? If FilmDatabase starts slowly - and cannot be used right away, then, well, do some kind of synchronization or add some kind of "delay"?

Comment: I'm not sure if i got your question right but if you want to initialize the database once and then use it within multiple tests setup a test fixture. Add database as member of the fixture class and override `SetUp()` to initialize the database.

Comment: @Mathias Schmid I don't think it would work - each test in test suite calls test suite ctor, then SetUp, then test body, then TearDown, then dtor (for each test, always in this order). So it would be initialized every time for each test.

Comment: @Quarra You are right. `SetUp()` is called for each test. Thanks.

Comment: @user4581301 it's giving me the same error

Comment: @PiotrNycz I mean that the constructor for the object takes around 0.1s to go through all the functions, so I'd like to create the object once and then use it in other tests.

Answer (score 0):

For creating an object once and using it in multiple tests the solution would be the [SetUpTestSuite](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/docs/advanced.md#sharing-resources-between-tests-in-the-same-test-suite). This function is called once before the execution of all tests in the same test fixture.

As an alternative you could fake the object that needs so long to initialize with a mock.